# How to pass array records from process page to index page in php?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, session, sweetalert

I am able to display array record in my process page and now i have to pass that records on index page.In array there are more than 10 records.
    Once that records will display on index after that i want to display all record on sweet alert popup.

What i am achieving...i am entering firstname in sweet alert and that fname will redirect process page and check that fname is available or not if available and how many users available on same name that all will redirect to index page.
    I am able to retrieve all records in process page but i have to redirect all records on index page.

```
  Getting error:Undefined variable: _SESSION and Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Would you help me in this?

**Process.php**

```
$array_record=array();
   $array_record['idsa']=$row["Id"];
  $array_record['Fname']=$row["First_name"];
  $array_record['Lname']=$row["Last_name"];
 $_SESSION['arr']=$array_record;
    // I tried below echo it display record on process page.


 /*
     $session=$_SESSION['arr'];
     foreach($session as $val)
     {
       echo $val.'<br>';
     }
    */
    header('Location: index.php?search=1');
```

**Index**

```
    if(!empty($_GET['search'])):

    $session=$_SESSION['arr'];
 foreach($session as $val)
 {
   echo $val.'<br>';
 }

    echo "<script>  
        setTimeout(function() {
            swal({
                title: 'You details !',
                text: '$val',
                type: 'info',
                closeOnCancel: true,
                html:true

             }, function() {
                window.location = 'index.php';
            });
        }, 1000);
    </script>";
      endif;?>
```

Comment: Remove the quotes in the URL encode function: urlencode($array_record[idsa])

Comment: where is `$searchdetails` coming from? Why does the url only have 1 parameter but you look for 4 in `index`?

Comment: Mr.RamRaider, If i will get output on index tha i will set $searchdetails

Comment: let me tell you what i am achieving...i am entering firstname in sweet alert and that fname will rediect process page and check that fname is available or not if available and how many users available on same name that all will redirect to index page..I am able to retrieve all records in process page but i have to redirect all records on index page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get all the array records from process.php to index.php, set that array in SESSION and get the session records in index.php.

index.php

```
<?php

//Submitting form here => action ="process.php"


?>
```

process.php

```
<?php
  //get the records from DB and set the values in session
  // Redirect to index.php

session_start();
$_SESSION['arr'] = $row; // $row is the array from Database
header("Location:index.php");
exit;
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
//Use the values in session 
//Unset after using 

session_start();
if($_SESSION['arr']){

$session=$_SESSION['arr']; 
foreach($session as $val) 
{ 
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($val); 
echo "</pre>"; 
}
//you can display the array using print_r($_SESSION).
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Ayyanar. Can you share the code.I am able ti display record in process.php but how to redirect all records from there.Please help me

Comment: Mr.Ayyanar Please check my code, I updated code using session but getting error on index page.

Comment: start the session wherever you are using php SESSION.so start the session session_start() in index.php file

Comment: have you started session in both index and process file?

Comment: Yes,In the top i entered <?php
session_start();
?>

Comment: ok fine.What is the exact error you are getting and in which file you are getting errors?

Comment: I am getting error on index page and errors are "Undefined variable: _SESSION and Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Comment: I think issue in $session=$_SESSION['arr']; in index page

Comment: put <?php if(isset($_SESSION['arr])){  //foreach loop here ?> and run the index file and also check your session_start() whether it is properly started     or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124199/discussion-between-hybreeder-and-ayyanar-veluchamy).

Answer (score 0):

I do not want to suggest that this method is the *best* method to do this, but it should help solve some of the issues you might be having.

```
header('Location: startEntry.php?data=' . base64_encode([$row["Id"],$row["First_name"],$row["Last_name"]]));
```

I think the bigger issue here is that you stated that you are passing:

> more than 10 records

At some point you might start hitting the URL length limits, regardless of what method you use.

Comment: sorry Mr.Abela, Not getting any out put.

Comment: That was meant as pseudo code, not exact code. it looks like i replaced `search` with `data`. and you are obviously going to have to base64 decode on the other end.

Comment: let me tell you what i am achieving...i am entering firstname in sweet alert and that fname will rediect process page and check that fname is available or not if available  and how many users available on same name that all will redirect to index page..hope you understood

Comment: I am able to retrieve all records in process page but i have to redirect all records on index page

Comment: I think you mis understand what *aspect* of your code I am trying to help with. I was only suggesting that instead of doing multiple `urlencode` within the *query* component of the url, that you consider combining all of the array values and using `base64`. Any issues outside of that scope, are **not** issues I was/am trying to solve with my suggested code above.

Comment: I understand that..Have you find any solution ?